# PyMC3 binomial switchpoint model highly dependent on testval

Tags: python, statistics, pymc3, mcmc

I've set up the following binomial switchpoint model in PyMC3:

```
with pm.Model() as switchpoint_model:

    switchpoint = pm.DiscreteUniform('switchpoint', lower=df['covariate'].min(), upper=df['covariate'].max())

    # Priors for pre- and post-switch parameters
    early_rate = pm.Beta('early_rate', 1, 1)
    late_rate = pm.Beta('late_rate', 1, 1)

    # Allocate appropriate binomial probabilities to years before and after current
    p = pm.math.switch(switchpoint >= df['covariate'].values, early_rate, late_rate)

    p = pm.Deterministic('p', p)

    y = pm.Binomial('y', p=p, n=df['trials'].values, observed=df['successes'].values)
```

It seems to run fine, except that it entirely centers in on one value for the switchpoint (999), as shown below.

[image]

Upon further investigation it seems that the results for this model are highly dependent on the starting value (in PyMC3, "testval").  The below shows what happens when I set the testval = 750.

```
switchpoint = pm.DiscreteUniform('switchpoint', lower=gp['covariate'].min(), 
upper=gp['covariate'].max(), testval=750)
```

[image]

I get similarly different results with additional different starting values.

For context, this is what my dataset looks like:
[image]

My questions are:

1. Is my model somehow incorrectly specified?
2. If it's correctly specified, how should I interpret these results?  In particular, how do I compare / select results generated by different testvals?  The only idea I've had has been using WAIC to evaluate out of sample performance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models with discrete values can be problematic, all the nice sampling techniques using the derivatives don't work anymore, and they can behave a lot like multi modal distributions. I don't really see why this would be *that* problematic in this case, but you could try to use a continuous variable for the switchpoint instead (wouldn't that also make more sense conceptually?).